# Existence of limit of certain numerical sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

suppose $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence satisfying the following:

(1)$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is decreasing and $a_n\geq 0$

(2)$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

(3)for some positive $\alpha,\beta$ the inequality $a\leq na_n\leq \beta$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Then does it follow that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n$ exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take $a_n = \frac{10 + (-1)^n}{n}$

Your three conditions are respected, but $na_n$ has no limit